# Datepicker don't allow past dates plus today

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi I have a bootstrap datepicker.  I want to grey out all past dates plus the date today on the calendar.  I know that I can grey out all past dates with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#delayed-spiffdate').datepicker({
        startDate: '-0d'
    });
});
```

But how do I grey out the current date?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude all past dates and today as well, then you need your `startDate` value to be `+1d`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#delayed-spiffdate').datepicker({
        startDate: '+1d'
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/tuuonpta/)

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

War10ck's answer is the cleanest. Worth noting, you can also set your datepicker parameters to whatever you like using a date object. Here's another answer that also works:

```
$(function () {
    $('#delayed-spiffdate').datepicker({
        startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qy8kvf39/